# Gives foreign key same number as parent id automatically

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table1 & table2 (with foreign key)  see tables :

[image]
I want query that can put same value automatically as

```
(INSERT INTO table2 (table2.foreignKey) VALUES (table1.id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) to do this.

It would look somewhat like this:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER insertIntoTable2 AFTER INSERT ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2 SET foreignKey = NEW.id;
  END;

|
delimiter ;
```